# My step daughter shook my baby

Tags: twins, step-parents

My guests were at home and I was decorating pudding for them. So, I gave my 12 month twin girls to my 14 year step daughter to take care just for 10 minutes in her room. I heard the babies crying continuously. After 5 minutes, I scooped my babies in my arm and thanked my step daughter for looking after them.

Then, she confessed that Rose was screaming a lot, so she shook her.

I am shocked. Would something happen to my baby? She is very quiet.

Comment: Have you ever instructed the step-daughter in the proper care of the toddlers, including telling her that shaking is not OK?

Comment: No, i haven't taught her. How would i know that shez gonna shake my baby. I gave only for 5 minutes .

Comment: well if you didn't instruct her on how to take care of a baby, then maybe you should consider that you were irresponsible by leaving the twins with her.

Comment: I left for exactly 5 minutes.

Comment: 5 minutes is sort of irrelevant. Certainly in the UK if you leave a 14 year old in charge it may be fine, but if something happens you are considered to be at fault, as it was your decision to leave them with the 14 year old. You need to educate a child in how to look after a baby, and yes, this includes 'Don't shake the baby'

Comment: Yes, i understood now. I should have told her clearly. I am more careful about keeping my.kids with her unsupervised, also now I clearly explained about babies: not to shake, hurt, smack etc. Today i taught her to formula feed also. Guess this is helping us to bond. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible for [shaking a young child (up to five years old) to cause trauma](http://kidshealth.org/parent/medical/brain/shaken.html). You should take Rose to a medical professional immediately.

I sincerely hope that Rose is fine and my heart goes out to you. I know that you've been trying hard with your step-daughter and I am saddened to hear that her behavior has gotten worse. Assaulting her sibling is completely inappropriate.

Comment: thanks. I took her to doctor.Rose is all right, just a bit scared.

Comment: I am glad to hear it!

Comment: @Tiffany: glad to hear she's ok. Have a serious talk to your partner and refer your step-daughter to the many cases of people being jailed for murder or attempted murder for shaking babies, e.g.
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/northern_ireland/1937374.stm
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/wales/north_east/4096524.stm
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10575775